# Delete empty rows in Multiple csv files in a Folder by using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Delete empty rows in Multiple CSV files in a Folder by using PowerShell

This is the code I am trying,  But it is writing empty files. Not Sure What's wrong with this code. Any suggestions would be appreciated. thank you.

```
$dest= "C:\Test"
Get-ChildItem $dest *.csv | ForEach-Object {
Get-Content $_.FullName | Where { $_.Replace(",","").trim() -ne "" }  | Out-File $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is expected, `Get-Content` and `Out-File` should not be sharing the same pipeline if reading and writing to the same file. Either, surround `Get-Content` with brackets or store the content in a variable and then write the file.

```
$dest = "C:\Test"
Get-ChildItem $dest *.csv | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_.FullName) | Where { $_.Replace(",","").trim() -ne "" } |
    Out-File $_.FullName
}

# OR

$dest = "C:\Test"
Get-ChildItem $dest *.csv | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_.FullName | Where { $_.Replace(",","").trim() -ne "" }) |
    Out-File $_.FullName
}

# OR

$dest = "C:\Test"
Get-ChildItem $dest *.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName | Where { $_.Replace(",","").trim() -ne "" }
    Out-File -InputObject $content -FilePath $_.FullName
}
```